# get remote artifact from a cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I've been able to provision my machine with a wildfly instance using [this cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/wildfly).

As you can see on documentation, I'am also able to set a webapp to deploy on ot using this LWRP:

```
wildfly_deploy 'my-app-1.0.war' do
  url 'http://artifacts.company.com/artifacts/my-app.1.0.war'
  runtime_name 'my-app.war'
end
```

As you can see, it's able to pick the artifact from any `url`. Nevertheless, I don't want my artifacts are public. So I was thinking about how to publish my artifacts in a secure way (using a ssh user) and get them from this cookbook.

So, this LWRP is able to pick a resource from a `path`

```
wildfly_deploy 'my-app-1.0.war' do
  path 'my-app.1.0.war'
  runtime_name 'my-app.war'
end
```

Is able to get a file, locate it and point to that in order for this cookbook to pick it. So, is there any ssh client, or scp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That custom resource uses jboss-cli.sh to do the install, so it supports whatever URL structure that script supports. The install command ends up being `bin/jboss-cli.sh -c 'deploy --url whatever ...'`. It doesn't look this support SCP or SFTP but I didn't look very closely.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. Finally, I've ended up chossing to download artifacts using aws cookbook. We're going to download artifacts and then set this path as deploy path. What do you think about that?

Comment: I know nothing of JBoss but using S3 as an artifact storage system is fine (except for the once a decade when it fails which happens to have been this week, but I still say you're fine :)